# Angular JS event for page rendered using ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**Background Scenario:**

I have an `ng-repeat` that populates my view, dynamically enlarging the `<div>` container.

I need to adjust the height of my `<div>` when the rendering is complete, and I also need to do that on every other page of my app.

I'm well aware of the `ready()` function:

```
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('ready')
    })
```

But this code, put in `app.js` get executed only on the first page opening (or reloading).

---

**Important note:**
I'm using `ui.router` to navigate through my "pages", so I call an `$state.transitionTo()' whenever I need to change page.

---

**Question:** Is there an Angular event that gets broadcasted whenever the page has fully rendered?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While looking for a solution, I've found that there is an ui.router event that gets called whenever the DOM has been fully rendered (on each new state transition)

The event is `$viewContentLoaded` and the syntax is pretty straight forward:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
            console.log('lock & loaded')
    })
```

I thought that could be useful to someone else,
Cheers

Comment: This seems to get fired for each and every nested view.  Is there a way to get this to fire just once when the whole page is rendered?

Comment: I'm not following this anymore, but the whole thing seems a bit f*cked up. Check out this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/685

Comment: I was frustrated with it firing for every nested view as well. I leveraged [lodash library's debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) function to limit how often it fires, and that cured the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use onEnter for uirouter like this,

```
$stateProvider
    .state('printer',
    {
        url: "/printer",
        views:
        {
            "view":
            {
                templateUrl: "/static/tpls/cloud/app/printer.php"
            }
        },
        onEnter: function(){
            try {
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.pageIn.postMessage("enter printer page");
            } catch(err) {
                console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
            }
        },
        onExit: function(){
            try {
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.pageOut.postMessage("leave printer page");
            } catch(err) {
                console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
            }
            document.getElementById('liveMovie').style.height='30px';
        }
    })
```